# Azure CLI DevOps get ID of created item with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm using PowerShell to create work items in Azure DevOps.

[image]

The item is created and there is a new item ID showing in PowerShell:

[image]

How do I get this ID to use in the next command to update this work item?

Thank you!

Comment: Which command are you ruuning ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I need the ID to run the following command: az boards work-item relation add --id
--relation-type
--target-id

Comment: Can you share the first command you run ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes Here you go: az boards work-item create --title "Test" --type "Product Backlog Item" --org "https://dev.azure.com/[my org name]/" --project "ADS Work" --description "Test"

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a Product Backlog Item, get the ID of that item, and create a task (child) under that PBI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get any field from the returns command you need to use `--query`.

**From the docs:**

> The Azure CLI uses the --query argument to execute a JMESPath query on
>   the results of commands. JMESPath is a query language for JSON, giving
>   you the ability to select and modify data from CLI output. Queries are
>   executed on the JSON output before any display formatting.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

**Usage:**

```bsh
$WorkitemID = az boards work-item create --title "test" --type "Issue" --organization https://dev.azure.com/XXX --project YYYY --query id
```

**output:**

```
Write-Output $WorkitemID
4857
```

Later, just use `$WorkitemID` variable and pass it to any az command you want.

Comment: Amit, thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help, hope you are doing well.